# Check if record exists in table before inserting new data

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

SQL Noob here.

Im using PHP PDO with named placeholders to insert data to my DB but I want to check if the data exists before I insert it.

Here is my statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dc_line_items_transactions WHERE order_id = '3784732' AND product_id = '435062') INSERT INTO dc_line_items_transactions (order_id,refund_id,user_id,transaction_date,product_id,line_item_id,line_subtotal,line_vat,line_total,dc_timestamp) VALUES (:order_id,:refund_id,:user_id,:transaction_date,:product_id,:line_item_id,:line_subtotal,:line_vat,:line_total,:dc_timestamp)
```

My PDO code works fine as Its being used by other classes to insert varying different types of data.

My error message is as follows:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dc_line_items_transactions WHERE order_id= '3784732' at line 1

Comment: I would propose to add a unique index on order_id, pruduct_id. In that case you can simply use a INSERT IGNORE which is much faster

Comment: In MySQL, `IF` is only allowed in programming blocks such as the bodies of stored procedures, functions, and triggers.